# How can I share a Gmail address book with my spouse?

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts

I have a well-maintained contact list in my Google Apps account. My wife is also on the same GApps domain, but her contact list is poorly maintained and only contains email addresses, not postal addresses or even full names.

Given that this is "Google Apps" for my own domain, we're technically a business site, so there ought to be a way to maintain a sort of "corporate-wide" address book that all domain accounts tap into.

**Does Google Apps have any kind of central contact list, and how can I maintain that?**
Note that I don't mean a list of internal addresses within my domain, but a **shared list of external contacts.**

It [looks like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/easy-way-to-share-contacts-between-users-in-a-google-apps-domain?rq=1) Google Apps doesn't have that kind of functionality, but I hope that the combined brains of SE would have a solution for us. Workarounds from [a few years ago](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/is-there-a-way-to-share-synchronize-contacts-between-google-accounts?lq=1) seem unsatisfying and perhaps obsolete.

Comment: http://www.gmailsharedcontacts.com/ seems to be the best of several bad options.

Comment: This also seems to be a duplicate of [What Contact sharing options are there in Google Apps?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/954) . Rather than creating a duplicate, you should add a bounty to the other question to get it more attention and (hopefully) some updated information.

Comment: @AlE. thanks, "best of bad" is probably accurate :) and their "free" option is ridiculous; they should call it "demo". As for the dupe question, I saw that one but it's 3½ years old and already has an accepted answer so I'm not sure a bounty on that one would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Torben, I see that you are using Google Apps. The bad news is that Google Apps doesn't have a built-in shared contacts solution, or even a very granular person-to-person solution. The good news is that Google permits you to share all your contacts with another member of your Google Apps domain (up to 25 different members) - check out the feature called "[Delegated Contacts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2590392?hl=en)".

As I said, it's not perfect (the other user can edit and access **all** your contacts), but for sharing your contact list with your wife, it should meet your need.

Comment: This looks like a very good solution - thank you! At least, as far as desktop use is concerned: _"Contacts delegation is available in the desktop web user interface only"_ so it won't help her while using her smartphone. (I know I didn't ask for that specifically, and might have to solve that bit with a one-time contact export/import.)

Answer (score 0):

[Flashpanel](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=14304%2018345705634006699039&category=&query=flashpanel) basic does a fair job of managing shared contacts in a Google Apps setup.

The Flashpanel enterprise version ($20 total per year for 2 users) adds functionality, like sharing contacts by tag or pushing to MyContacts. (many features others too).

Flashpanel app replaced the SherpaTools app mentioned in the 2010 topic.